# Executar função javascript no php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou construindo um sistema de chat em php, e na função de verificação de clientes onlines que vai ser um ajax chamando a um arquivo php de 30 em 30s, e neste arquivo haverá um foreach que irá trazer cada usuário e fazer a verificação, e preciso fazer uma função, que ao constar que o cliente está offline altere a class do html no painel do atendente para offline, dentro do foreach.
Ou seja, para cada usuário que ele ver que está offline ele já iria setando dentro do foreach que o cliente está online ou ofline alterando a class dele.

Seria possível rodar essa função JS dentro do php? ou no php chamar uma função JS?

Comment: Usa esse Ajax para retornar algum tipo de informação (um flag) para detectar que o usuário está off e em seguida alterar a classe.

Comment: é que este foreach iria verificar cada usuario que está sendo pego no foreach e já setar todos os usuário que estivessem ofline, com a sua solução eu iria conseguir, só que apenas 1 usuário e não todos de uma vez, me corrija se eu estiver errado por favor, pois sou novo na programação e no php.

Comment: Digamos que eu sou um usuário, e estou na página. Pelo que entendi, esse Ajax não funciona "só pra mim", ele é rodado ao fundo para o sistema todo, é isso?

Comment: eu tenho um ajax para clientes(que seria seu caso) e outro para atendentes. no seu casso quando voce logasse haveria um javascript rodando que salvaria a cada 1minuto um arquivo json com a data e hora que foi feita a verificação que vc está online, e no lado do atendente haveria um javascript que usuaria um ajax para verificar se existe esse arquivo e caso existir compara a diferença da hora atual e da hora salva no seu arquivo, se o resultado ultrapassar 1 minuto você está ofline, senão vc está online. é basicamente isso.

Answer (score -1):

Galera consegui resolver da seguinte forma, eu fiz as verificações dos usuário que estavam online no arquivo php, e após verificar eu coloquei o id dos usuários online em um array e retornei esse array ao JS, no js percorri um for que para cada id do array marcasse como online.
Dai eu fico fazendo essa requisição de 10 em 10 segundos.
Obrigado aos que ajudaram.